# C# EF Core Web Api Expand Is Null On Entity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, odata

I’m using the net core 3.1 framework on my web api project. My problem is, that I have an entity (“FirebaseUser”) without db context. But this entity has a one to one releationship to an entity (“Mitarbeiter”) with db context. Then I expand the “FirebaseUser” entity with “Mitarbeiter” entity, the attribute “Mitarbeiter” is null.
The sql statement for selection the “Mitarbeiter” is not executed. I think, because I’m returning an entity, who has no db context. Has anyone an idee?

FirebaseUser entity declaration:

```
    [NotMapped]
    [FirestoreData]
    public class FirebaseUser : FirestoreObject
    {

        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string sUid { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string sEmail { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public bool? bAlwaysMustLogin { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty(ConverterType = typeof(GuidConverter))]
        public Guid? sMitarbeiterId { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty]
        public bool? bDeleted { get; set; }
        public string sPasswort { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("sMitarbeiterId")]
        public virtual Mitarbeiter Mitarbeiter { get; set; }
    }
```

FirebaseUser controller code

```
        [EnableQuery]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
        {

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", FirestoreObject.CredentialPath);
            FirestoreDb oDb = FirestoreDb.Create(FirestoreObject.FirestoreDb);
            DocumentSnapshot oBenutzerSnapshot = await oDb.Collection("benutzer_benu").Document(key).GetSnapshotAsync();
            if (!oBenutzerSnapshot.Exists)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            FirebaseUser oUser = oBenutzerSnapshot.ConvertTo<FirebaseUser>();
            return Ok(oUser);
        }
```

The result looks like that
("/FirebaseUser?$expand=Mitarbeiter")

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://localhost:52854/$metadata#FirebaseUser(Mitarbeiter())/$entity",
  "sUid": "2BYJSDtifrV14yuw06XDSvrlz363",
  "sEmail": "werner-eder@t-online.de",
  "bAlwaysMustLogin": null,
  "sMitarbeiterId": null,
  "bDeleted": false,
  "sPasswort": null,
  "sId": "7uIDmH8QHRqbONZaoA8o",
  "sAngelegtVonUid": null,
  "dAngelegtAm": null,
  "Mitarbeiter": null
}
```

Comment: Specifying the `ForeignKeyAttribute` on a property of a type decorated with `NotMappedAttribute` appears contradictory.

Comment: The defenition for NotMappedAttribute says: "The NotMapped attribute is used to specify that an entity or property is not to be mapped to a table or column in the database.". My entity "FirebaseUser" is not mapped to a table. When i remove the attribute, nothing is change.

Comment: I know that. If you read what I said, I am asking why you are applying the `ForeignKeyAttribute` given that. It makes the code seem confused which may well be the case.

Comment: I applying the ForeignKeyAttribute attribute, because the property “MitarbeiterId” is a foreign key to mitarbeiter. No matter whether the entity “FirebaseUser” is mapped to a database table or not. 
But why is no sql statement executed, for selecting the employee by expanding?

Comment: That is at once meaningless and very confusing. The purpose of that attribute is to encode relational metadata, a foreign key constraint. This object is not stored in a relational database. As for why no SQL is generated. How could it be generated? You have two completely unrelated data sources and must manually retrieve any semantically connected data as needed.